# Restore git submit history from github

Tags: git, github

A disgruntled developer who left a project sabotaged the git repository and I have now been brought on. I am unsure exactly what she did but here are the facts:

- There was a full commit history in github before and I know the SHA of the commit I want to make the current head
- I can view this commit only buy using the SHA in the github url: https://github.com/[USER]/[Project]/tree/d5f7068fcef33791418e3e1d2b954162403e7c8b
- When I check out the project locally it does not pull in any history other than the last commit she made which is just a blank readme file:

  ```
  $ git log
  commit 4cbfb43f76a41df6de6f66354566377c2ef2ab0d
  Author: Author
  Date:   Sun Sep 1 20:39:47 2013 +0300

      initial
  ```

I cannot rebase because my local repo doesn't know about the commit with the SHA because only this one commit comes down from github. The history that I want seems to be orphaned.

Is there a way to check out the other commit via SHA directly from github (origin) and then make the head point to that?

Any other ideas?

Comment: do you have any local clones (on any machine) that contain the good commit (d5f7...)? if yes, it would be much easier to recover from that.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't.

Comment: @roycef have you tried contacting [GitHub customer support](https://github.com/contact)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up downloading the zip of the repo from the last good commit on github, then added and committed all of the files to the sabotaged repo. I lost all of the previous commit history but at least have a working repo back now.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do a `git merge <SHA>`, which, because the bad dev did a rebase, will complain, but given that she simply rebased to the initial commit, it sounds like solving the conflict will be relatively easy.

If your local repository doesn't know about the commit -- but the remote one does -- then try making a new clone of the remote repository and seeing if the commit you're looking for is there. As far as I understand git, if the commit is present remotely, and you clone the repository, you should be able to access that commit.

Comment: It didn't work, my local repo doesn't know about the SHA I need. This is my main problem.

Comment: Modified my answer with a new suggestion: if cloning *still* doesn't work, then that's really interesting. :/